# Timeout Expired - Session - How to Fix

Tags: c#, sql

Hi all and thanks in advance. I am trying to fix a method that inserts information to a database table. Currently its experiencing timeouts because its running in a while loop that is taking too long to process all the contents. While I know I could just increase the command timeout I don't think that solves the problem because I think its the code. But I'm not certain what the correct fix is. I have access to Dapper and I wonder if it would be more efficient to make a method that passes the necessary variables and executes just a quick simple statement for that group then goes to get the next one? Or is that just perpetuating what's below just in a different way? Should I move this out of the code and onto the server for better performance?

UPDATE Full error message:

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
>   File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\6caa4c91\19b853c6\App_Web_o3102kpb.9.cs
>   Method: ProcessRequest   Line Number : 0
>   Inner Exception:   {Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   File: z:\inetpub\wwwroot\SessionTransfer.aspx.cs
>   Method: AddSessionToDatabase   Line Number : 94
>   Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   File: z:\inetpub\wwwroot\SessionTransfer.aspx.cs   Method: Page_Load   Line Number : 33  }

Here is the original code:

> ```
>       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
> ```

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        int i = 0;
        string strSql, guid = GetGuid();

        string temp = "";

        while (i < Session.Contents.Count)
        {
            if (Session.Contents[i] == null)
                temp = "";
            else {
                if ((Session.Contents[i].ToString().Trim().Length) > 0)
                    temp = Session.Contents[i].ToString().Replace("'", "''");
                else
                   temp = "";
            }

            strSql = "INSERT INTO SessionTable (GUID, SessionKey, SessionValue) " + 
                     "VALUES ('" + guid + "', '" + Session.Contents.Keys[i].ToString() + "', '" + temp + "')";
            cmd.CommandText = strSql;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            i++;
        }

        con.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();

        return guid;
```

UPDATE - FINAL SOLUTION:

> ```
>       var SessionList = new List<Session>();
> ```

```
        while (i < Session.Contents.Count)
        {
            string temp = "";
            if (Session.Contents[i] == null)
                temp = "";
            else
            {
                temp = (Session.Contents[i].ToString().Trim().Length) > 0 ? Session.Contents[i].ToString().Replace("'", "''") : "";
            }
            var s = new Session
            {
                TempGuid = guidTemp,
                Contents = Session.Contents[i] != null ? Session.Contents[i].ToString() : null,
                Temp = temp
            };
            SessionList.Add(s);

            i++;
        }
        mySession = SerializationUtilities.SerializeObjectToXML(SessionList);

        using (var con = new SqlConnection()) 
        {
            con.ExecuteHGW("Transfer", new { mySession }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
```

Then on the SQL side I just put the XML in a table and did one single insert statement against the table, time is significantly improved.

Comment: First question is the timeout message is that actually bubbling out from your sql or from the time taken to execute the query? Is it possible to include the actual error message? How many times is this looping through?

Comment: I've included the full error message, in this particular example the Session.Contents.Count is 38. I have other errors where the count has varied 39, 37, etc.

Comment: Looks like a web client is waiting for a response from the server and timing out. Is it possible for you to run your while loop in a different thread and return the Guid right away?

Comment: @MisterXero When the guid is returned then the page goes to a Response.Redirect to another page, can I still have the while loop running in another thread while its doing that?

Comment: @ElaineK Is this logic running on the client or server? I believe if you start the while loop in something like a worker thread from the threadpool class it will continue in the background until it completes.

Comment: @MisterXero This is server side code. The concern I have is that although this could work, if the user needs access to a entry that is entered into the database by this method then when they get to the next page, or whatever page they may go to, the session data for that user may not be accurate, would that be a correct assumption?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems with running it on another thread then. It just may be hard to determine whether or not the code executed successfully.

Comment: @ElaineK is it possible for you to verify that you can execute the SQL (in code) at least once?  Perhaps adjust the while loop to only run a couple iterations before exiting to make sure there is not another underlying issue.

Comment: @Encryption - I can execute the SQL in code several times without a problem when I debug it but eventually it hangs and there's no consistency as to when it hangs it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you 2 improvements:

1. in the loop you are executing insert statements one by one against db. It takes much time to open connection to db then send the query, execute it and return result. It is much better to batch them. So gather like 10,000 of such insert statements, build the whole instuction with StringBuilder and execute it against db in one go. This will really increase the speed of your app. Amount of Insert instructions in one batch you should choose yourself basing on system tests.
2. If after applying 1) hint the problem with timeout still occurs I would suggest 2 possible solutions:

   a). do not send all elements to be processed against db to web service at once but instead, as previoulsy, batch them (apply second batching). So for instance send to web service 50,000 elements to be insterted, then wait for confirmation from web service and then proceed with next batch. The big advantage is that you can show to user easily progress bar showing him current operation state.

   b). send all items to be processed against db at once but do not wait for result. In your app just show that items are processed and each 10 s send to web service request to ask if the job is finished. When it is finished signal it to user.

Comment: Between MisterXero and mr100 the solution I went with more closely ties in with the idea presented here so I'm going to mark this correct but edit my question with what my final solution looked like.